# Twisted Tensor Product

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm currently reading Brown's paper on Twisted tensor products. Given a fibration: $F\rightarrow X\rightarrow B$.  When this fibration is 'nice' i.e. base is paracompact and the total space is locally a product this paper gives a chain equivalence between the chain complex of the total space $C(X)$ and the twisted product of chains on the fibre $C(F)$ with chains on the base $C(B)$ relative to a twisting cochain.

The construction of the twisted cochain is a proof of existence by induction. I was wondering whether anyone knew what a twisting cochain would look like in practice. Say for a Hopf fibration or some Lie group fibration and what an obstruction would be for the chain equivalence to descend to a ring isomorphism in the cohomology.